# What are viable chemicals that could replace caffeine/catnip for alien species?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, food

There's a fairly well known trope of [Alien Catnip](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienCatnip) where some unassuming chemical is actually an alien's version of [coffee](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Uncoffee), catnip or some other stimulant.

Examples include catfood from District 9, and sour milk from Alien Nation.

I would like to pick something for my aliens, but have it be chemically justified or at minimum science based. I want them to go crazy over this stuff, but not make the reader going crazy thinking I've hand waved it. It also needs to be something that can be justifiably common, and not something only made in a lab.

I'm assuming they have comparable biology (to earth life), but aren't exactly the same as earth life, so that the chemical can still activate a brain in some way that I can explain.

My criteria are:

- Something originally available on earth
- A chemical that is able to cross a blood brain barrier (I'm assuming human's are a good analogy here)
- Something that is not so wide spread on earth that it's ubiquitous.

Comment: since they are aliens their biochemistry is so unknown you can use basically any biomolecule as long as it is rare. A lot of these effects have nothing to do with the molecule itself but what receptors it happens to trigger.

Comment: @john edited for clarity, "I'm assuming they have comparable biology (to earth life), but aren't exactly the same as earth life" so it's not "so unknown" that you can go crazy and pick anything.

Comment: There's enough examples on Earth to demonstrate that you could pick almost anything. Nicotine is a toxin to insects, humans use it as a stimulant. A medium sized chocolate Easter bunny is trivially consumed by most people: it would kills a small to medium sized dog because of the theobromine..

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based. If they're "human enough" then any narcotic or stimulant will do. Without a specific and thorough description of what "aren't exactly the same" is, it's factually impossible to provide a [tag:science-based] answer.

Comment: The answer is "literally anything non-toxic". VTC:Opinion-Based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What makes a bio-available stimulant?

The criteria I'm setting for viable chemicals is that it must be naturally occurring (that is you can get it from plants/animals). It also must be plausible to cross whatever passes for the aliens blood brain barrier (so not too large a molecule), and not be so common that it would always be in effect (no O<sub>2</sub> molecules for instance, but that could be possible in other atmospheres). I'm also assuming a human/earth animal like biology, because outside of that you could justify almost anything.

#### [Flavenoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavonoid)

These are a large family of extremely common chemicals on earth:

> Flavonoids are widely distributed in plants, fulfilling many functions.

In fact they [occur in many foods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavonoid#Dietary_sources), and [can cross the human blood-brain barrier](https://doi.org/10.1017%2FS0007114508965776) (so in theory, could cross our alien equivalent).

> Emerging evidence suggests that dietary phytochemicals, in particular flavonoids, may exert beneficial effects on the central nervous system

Good (but non-exhaustive) examples of potential flavenoids include:

- [Rutin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutin) available in Capers and Black Olives among other things.
- [Fisetin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisetin) mainly available in strawberries.
- [Kaempferol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaempferol) Capers again, but also saffron.
- [Myricetin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myricetin) Carob and Fenel this time.
- [Quercetin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercetin) Capers once more, and lovage leaves.

It looks like, if we take this route, there's lots of good examples, but it seems mostly capers for some reason.

#### [Alkaloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaloid)

Caffeine and Cocaine are already alkaloids, so it makes sense to look here for more. They have a long history of being extracted from plants, so they'd be available to the aliens.

> Many have found use in traditional or modern medicine, or as starting points for drug discovery. Other alkaloids possess psychotropic (e.g. psilocin) and stimulant activities (e.g. cocaine, caffeine, nicotine, theobromine),[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histamine) and have been used in entheogenic rituals or as recreational drugs. Alkaloids can be toxic too (e.g. atropine, tubocurarine).[11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biogenic_amine) Although alkaloids act on a diversity of metabolic systems in humans and other animals, they almost uniformly evoke a bitter taste.

Alkaloid examples (deliberately avoiding the common human stimulants):

- [Yohimbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yohimbine) comes from the bark of two separate trees, as well as [other plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yohimbine#Other_plants).
- [Mimosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosine) occurs in some [Mimosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa) plants as well as all [Leucaena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucaena).
- [Quinine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinine) is a well known anti-malarial, that is [naturally occuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinine#Natural_occurrence). It's also in tonic water, which might make it very available to aliens - Gin and Tonic, hold the gin...
- [Physostigmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physostigmine) occurs in some beans native to Africa, as well as [Manchineel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchineel) aka the little apple of death.

There are several other potential alkaloids, but almost all seem to have the basis in plants

#### Others

Some other chemicals make good candidates such as:

- [Biogenic Amines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biogenic_amine) like:

  - [Histamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histamine):

  > Fermented foods and beverages naturally contain small quantities of histamine due to a similar conversion performed by fermenting bacteria or yeasts. Sake contains histamine in the 20–40 mg/L range; wines contain it in the 2–10 mg/L range.[10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histamine)

  - [Cadaverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadaverine) and [Putrescine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putrescine) occur in rotting food, but can still behave like other amines

  > In humans, molecular modelling and docking experiments have shown that putrescine fits into the binding pocket of the human TAAR6 and TAAR8 receptors

#### Conclusion, and how to find more

Any of the above could be viable stimulants, so long as their chemistry matches something in the xenobiology of your aliens.

Overall, the trick I've found is to find a similar chemical substance, look at what chemical group it's in and then track down which of those sibling-chemicals could be available naturally in plants and animals.

Comment: I'm tempted to make this a community wiki, to encourage people to add/remove good examples, but I'm not sure if that would have the desired effect. Thoughts? Ideas? Warnings?

Comment: It took me only a few minutes on Google to find all of this and more - but none of it is particularly useful for anything other than humanity. How do you imagine this changing such that, e.g., cat food (District 9, your example) becomes any of these things?

Comment: @jbh that's going about this question backwards. Your starting with a food, and then trying to pick a suitable chemical. I'm not looking at what chemicals might be viable and available and then working or what foods they're in. If I'd have picked histamine or putrescine/cadaverine though, I could have noted it can be formed from amino acids found in cat food. But that's a step further than I'd have initially considered.

Comment: Backwards? I'm trying to understand the point of the question and the answer. An alien physiology would need to be defined such that an author could come up with a science-based chemical composition with a negative side-effect. Or, more realistically, an author would have to start by choosing a chemical compound (like a food) here on Earth and then designing the alien physiology (or, more likely, "declaring it to be so") that would react to it. Either way, this Q & A seem useless as they're only focused on humans, which can be derived by a trivial Google search.